# Discrete Math Probability

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose we toss a fair coin four ($4$) times.

The outcome of the $1$st three tosses is {HHH}.

What is the probability of the next toss being heads $P(head)$?

$P(Head)=$ possible outcome/total outcome $=\frac{4}{8}$

Is it $\frac{1}{2}$?

Options:

A. $P(head) = \frac{1}{16}$

B. $P(head) = 3\frac{1}{8}$

C. $P(head) = \frac{1}{12}$

D. $P(head) = \frac{1}{2}$

Is it? D

Please let me know if I am correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you are calculating the probability of the head after 3 heads before the 3 were tossed then it would be 2^-4=1/16. If you had just tossed it 3 times it would be 2^-1=1/2.

Comment: I was correct its 1/2 thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's D ($\frac{1}{2}$).

Past results do not affect the probability of future ones (as far as our limited perception of space–time continuum tells us).

Comment: hey can you let me know how to properly format questions on stack exchange is there a forum or something sorry Im still new thanks

Comment: @user149068: First of all, just edit your own question and see the changes that I have applied there. Second, the language used for mathematical expressions is called *LaTex*, so every time you want to write down a mathematical expression and you're not sure how, just search *LaTex* in your favorite search engine (which is Google, as far as our limited perception of search engines tells us).